# SVN 1.7.5-1 segmentation fault everywhere

Tags: svn, segmentation-fault, fedora

I'm using SVN client on Fedora 17 at work and today it stopped working. Everything I do, even `svn` only or `svn --version` or whatever with SVN throws **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

I've restarted the machine, reinstalled SVN (removed and installed again) but no luck. Can't find anything helpful online (only old version issues or problems with a specific SVN command) but this is for the entire client, every command.

Any tips on that?

Comment: end of strace log:

`mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1bf9e57000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f1bf9e57880) = 0
mprotect(0x7f1bfd1a9000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f1bfd5e0000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f1bfa079000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f1c0005f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f1c00268000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f1c00479000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x8} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

`

Comment: Should anyone suffer from the same issue, I downgraded to the rpm version hosted here - http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=314940